# Delete multiple columns in multiple Excel files present in a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I had tried this code for one excel sheet.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Multiple_Columns ()
Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

This worked well for one excel sheet in the folder, I want to loop through all the excel files in that folder and do it in one go, any help is appreciated.

After adding the logic of traversing through all the files in the folder

```
​Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings
'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"
'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
 'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)    
 'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents

 'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
  wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)
  wb.Worksheets(1).Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Delete
 'Save and Close Workbook
  wb.Close SaveChanges:=True      
 'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
  DoEvents
 'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
Loop
ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Problem is Compatibility checker, have to disable that.

Comment: you need to loop through `Workbooks`, then loop through `Worksheets`, and then you can use this code.

Comment: Yes, I have done that too

Comment: So share with us your full code, as this one is missing some crucial parts

Comment: Tried your code with multiple .xls in a folder using Excel 2013, works for me. If the compatibility checker annoys (in my case I just had to press OK for each workbook with your macro, it still worked) you just search for a solution on the web, there are a few sites showing up.